# How to query all VMs in a subscription without Tags

Tags: powershell, azure, tags, azure-cli

I want to be able to query all the VMs in my Azure subscription to list machines that do not have Tags.

```
$resources = Get-AzureRmResource
foreach($resource in $resources)
{
    if ($resource.Tags -eq $null)
    {
        echo $resource.Name, $resource.ResourceType
    }
}
```

Above code shows all the resources without Tags (nic, lb, etc.) I only want to see Virtual Machines

Comment: Find out how to identify that `$resource` is a VM then?  It returns a `PSObject` so [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermresource?view=azurermps-5.6.0#outputs) doesn't really tell what members it has, but I'm sure you can figure out which member corresponds to the resource type.  Then, you can look for null tags `-and $resource.Type -eq 'VM'` or whatever it ends up being

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use this:

```
Get-AzureRMVM | Where-Object { $_.tags }
```

which is a easier to read\understand

**edit**: sorry, you need the reverse:

```
Get-AzureRMVM | Where-Object { $_.tags.count -eq 0 }
```